# URLRewriteFilter hide parameters

Tags: tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I have a url that looks like this:

http://example.com/example/

When I click on a link in the website I want thre browser to show http://example.com/example/link1 but my rule is showing http://example.com/example/?p=link1

How do I hide the /?a=

```
    <rule>
         <from>^/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$</from> 
         <to type="redirect">%{context-path}/?a=$1</to> 
    </rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the question, you can just remove the `/?a=` from your  tag like

```
<to type="redirect">%{context-path}/$1</to>
```